# Incrementing "Name" in jQuery output

Tags: php, jquery, html, function, increment

```
<script>
function addRow()
{
$('#newitems tr:last').before('<tr><td><input type="text" name="itemnum" value="value"></td></tr>');
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to set a variable to increment the "name" and "value" of the function above each time the addRow() function is called. In other words I want the following output:

**First call to addRow() returns**

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="itemnum1" value="value1"></td></tr>
```

**Second call to addRow() returns**

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="itemnum2" value="value2"></td></tr>
```

**Third call to addRow() returns**

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="itemnum3" value="value3"></td></tr>
```

etc, etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, you can do such thing:

```
<script>
var i = 1;
function addRow()
{
$('#newitems tr:last').before('<tr><td><input type="text" name="itemnum'+i+'" value="value'+i+'"></td></tr>');
i += 1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's it exactly and I feel kind of dumb for not remembering how to concatenate a string like that in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
var i = 1;
function addRow(){
    $('#newitems tr:last').before('<tr><td><input type="text" name="itemnum' + i + '" value="value' + i + '"></td></tr>');
    i++;
}
```

or

```
function addRow(num_rows){
    for(i=0;i<num_rows; i++){
        $('#newitems tr:last').before('<tr><td><input type="text" name="itemnum' + i + '" value="value"></td></tr>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, assign a counter variable that's available within the scope of your function. Then, on each iteration of your function, append the counter value to your output string and increment the counter:

```
<script>
  var count = 1;
  function addRow() {
    $('#newitems tr:last').before('<tr><td><input type="text" name="value'+count+'" value="value'+count+'"></td></tr>');
    count++;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you'd need a value to hold the number.  Let's call it `i`:

```
var i = 1;
```

Then any time you output that line, use the current value of `i` and increment it:

```
$('#newitems tr:last').before('<tr><td><input type="text" name="itemnum' + i + '" value="value' + i++ + '"></td></tr>');
```

Note that I increment it on only one usage, otherwise it would be incremented twice.  Using the `++` operator means that it *evaluates* to the current value, but increments it after the evaluation.